# Implementing location tracking with Firebase JobDispatcher

Tags: android, firebase, gps, android-service

I am making a location tracking application for android devices but there is a news that Google will stop supporting Unbound Background Services from Android O onwards (Android will throw IllegalStateException if you use the startService() method in future releases). Then the only option left is to make the app with the Firebase JobDispatcher API, but my application needs continuous location tracking which can be done only with background services. So I need help in my approach, as to how can I continuously track the device and update the server regularly with location points even with this Firebase JobDispatcher API. There is no proper reference site that I can take help from. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you using Firebase JobDispatcher with Google Play Services for tracking location?

Comment: Yes currently, but the thing is, it is not continuous specifically when the device is in the doze mode.

Comment: @ShubhamBhardwaj did you got any good solution?

Comment: @RahulSharma, unfortunately soon after I was assigned some other work, so wasn't able to continue researching on that, but I think this may help: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates